# How to have per-platform classes in Java?

Tags: java, multiplatform

I'm writing a serial interface in Java. It uses JNA to access underlying native API. I'have defined a `SerialPort` interface containing classic methods (open, read, write, close, ...):

```
public interface SerialPort {
    void open(String portName) throws IOException;
    void close() throws IOException;
    void write(byte[] data) throws IOException;
    byte[] read(int bytes) throws IOException;
    byte[] read(int bytes, int timeout) throws IOException;
    void setConfig(SerialConfig config) throws Exception;
    SerialConfig getConfig();
}
```

Now, I would like to have implementation based on the running platform. What is the good way to do it ? Do I have to load classes at runtime ?

If I create two classes implementing this interface (`SerialPortUnix` and `SerialPortWin32`). I want to have a function which would return one or the other based on the platform.

How can I do this properly ?

Thanks,

Comment: an alternative to a factory pattern and run-time implementation resolution would be to use a dependency injection framework (e.g. Spring) with different profiles/builds for different operating systems, i.e. you will produce different artifacts for different operating systems.

Comment: WHat's the advantage of such a solution ? It seems complex.

Comment: it for example better fits open-close principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) since you don't need to  modify the `if-else` construct whenever you want to add a new OS support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement different `SerialPort` instances for different platforms. Assume we have `SerialPort` implementations: `serialPortWindows` for Windows, and `serialPortLinux` for Linux

Then use `System.getProperty("os.name");` call to determine the platform and use relevant class.

If your app runs either on windows or linux, try this example:

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
SerialPort serialPortImpl;
if (os.substring("windows") != -1) {
   // use windows serial port class
   serialPortImpl = serialPortWindows; 
} else {
   // use linux serial port class
   serialPortImpl = serialPortLinux;     
}

// now use serialPortImpl, it contains relevant implementation
// according to the current operating system
```

Comment: Would it be advisable to use a Factory pattern here ?

Comment: yes, sure. This code can (and should) be refactored according to the current particular task. It is a plain/dirty example, how to solve the task in general.

Comment: Where could I put the factory method ? I can't a static methid in my SerialPort interface. Should I create a SerialPortFactory class ?

Comment: As an  option you can create `SerialPortFactory` class with a static method like `getSerialPortImpl`, that returns relevant `SerialPort` implementation.

Comment: @ThibautD. - you can have static method on interface in java 8 :) or, have a nested `Factor` class in `SerialPort`. However, the simplest is just do `Class.forName("SerialPort"+osName).newInstance()`

Comment: Ok I tested it works correctly. I don't have to use specific builds, if I don't instance a class which do JNA calls to win32 on Linux it works fine. Thanks!